# How to influence line breaks in lstlistings?

Tags: listings, line-breaking, code

Latex breaks lines at odd positions in code listings, for example, before a comma or after opening quotation marks. Is there any way to influence the line breaking strategy or to suggest where a line should be split?

I am aware of the workaround to escape within the code and to surround parts with an mbox (e.g., `print(~\mbox{"ggggg"}~);`), however, this has the side effect that the formatting (e.g., string higlighting) is no longer applied. Therefore, I am wondering whether a better way exists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    escapechar=~
}

\newcommand{\highlightInListing}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
 public static void x() {
    System.out.println(ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff, "ggggggggggggg"); 
    System.out.println("ffffffffffffffffffff", "ggggggggggggg"); 
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can influence the line breaks with `\nolinebreak` and `\linebreak` - escaping these won't affect the coloring

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    escapechar=~,
    stringstyle=\color{purple},
}

\newcommand{\highlightInListing}[1]{\textbf{\textcolor[rgb]{1,0.41,0.13}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=java]
 public static void x() {
    System.out.println("ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"~\nolinebreak~, ~\linebreak~"ggggggggggggg"); 
    System.out.println("ffffffffffffffffffff", ~\linebreak~"ggggggggggggg"); 
 }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why `\nolinebreak` does not work in the second case (and I would need to use `\linebreak` instead? (`linebreak` messes with the listings background)

Comment: @nrainer What do you mean with "does not work"?

Comment: Using a `\nolinebreak` after `"` does not have any effect (i.e., if I replace `linebreak` with `nolinebreak` in the second printline and move it after the `"` character).

Comment: Using the escapechar + \linebreak is the only solution when using \ttfamily for your listings

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use the lstlisting with the option `breakatwhitespace=true`.